# how to call the onDraw method of a SurfaceView using a thread class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-canvas, surfaceview

So iv been trying to figure out how to draw shapes and images to a surfaceview. iv been using multiple tutorials. but now im lost. i have a Thread that has my game loop and from what i understand im am to have all variable updates in this loop

```
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (running) {
         c = null;
         try {
             c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
             synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
              //Insert methods to modify positions of items in onDraw()
             }
         } finally {
             if (c != null) {
                 surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
             }
         }
    }

}
```

I have a surfaceView that has the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method. Say i want to add oval to my screen how do i do that from my while loop in my thread

i currently have these variables in my thread class

```
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private gameMain gamePanel; //my surfaceview class
private boolean running;
```

and do i need to have this in my surfaceview class ?

```
setWillNotDraw(false);
```

if im doing it completely wrong people point it out. i do not wish to use openGL or any libraries